# How to keep objects throughout multiple activities and fragments in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-activity

I created a class "Car" and I have a list of instantiated Cars created in my MainActivity.
I have a master/detail flow with an ItemListActivity as well, which should be able to receive a specific car from MainActivity.

This master/detail flow works as a Settings Menu, where there are multiple fragments acting as different types of settings (Build, engine, etc.) [image]

The master/detail flow needs to then get all the changes made to the edit text, and update the fields of the Car that it received, and than **send it back** to MainActivity.

I'm not sure if this is 1) possible or 2) the best way to approach this problem. Should I be keeping the list of objects in MainActivity? Is there a better way to keep an object that will be used globally?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having a `ViewModel` in your activity and get the `ViewModel` instance from your fragments as follows.

```
carViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(CarViewModel.class);
```

The `CarViewModel` might have the necessary elements to build a car and from each fragments, you can just update that `ViewModel` that resides in your activity.

The `CarViewModel` might have a function call `buildCar` that you can trigger when you are done building your car from different fragments. The `ViewModel` will be bound to the lifecycle of the activity and hence if you close the activity, the information will be lost.

Comment: By activity do you mean the mainactivity or the settingsactivity (master/detail flow)?
And I'm a little confused by this, do you mean I would buiuld the car from  each fragment (so just retrieve all the data from the edittexts in the fragments) and then set the selected car to the newly built car?

Comment: I assume the master/detail flow is in the `SettingsActivity`. In that case, you can have the `ViewModel` in the `SettingsActivity`.